# Programmatically RelativeLayout layouting issue

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have an Achievement dialog, and would like this:

[image: Description]

And this is my code, each achievement is a relative layout, and all are contained in a LinearLayout (pnlAchievement):

```
            RelativeLayout pnlItem = new RelativeLayout(Parent);
        pnlItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txtItemName = new TextView(Parent);
        txtItemName.setText(ACHIEVEMENTS_NAME[i]);
        txtItemName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txtAchived = new TextView(Parent);
        txtAchived.setText(Achived[i] ? "Achieved!" : "Not Achieved!");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpAchived = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rlpAchived.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rlpAchived.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, txtItemName.getId());
        txtAchived.setLayoutParams(rlpAchived);

        TextView txtDescription = new TextView(Parent);
        txtDescription.setText(ACHIEVEMENTS_DESCRIPTION[i]);
        txtDescription.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpDesc = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rlpDesc.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, txtItemName.getId());
        rlpDesc.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        txtDescription.setLayoutParams(rlpDesc);

        pnlItem.addView(txtItemName);
        pnlItem.addView(txtAchived);
        pnlItem.addView(txtDescription);
        pnlAchievement.addView(pnlItem);
```

It work well list all the achievements, but the description is NOT below the Name, it is OVER the Name, like this:

[image]

And, can you please tell me how to add the line between every item without using Canvas (this is not very important, but if there is, it's better)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use RelativeLayout.BELOW

For the line you can use a Label with a backgroundcolor.

Comment: Thanks for the line. But I changed to BELOW it also doesn't work :(

Comment: Nothing else, I just change RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM to RelativeLayout.BELOW, the result stay the same! And after that, I switch the width of rlpDesc to FILL_PARENT, and it doesn't change anything, too.

Comment: Can you try to set an id for the txtItemName; txtItemName.setId(123456);

Comment: Yup, it works now ^^~ Thanks a lot. So the Id is the problem!